# Creating a char array, whose size is given by parameter - C++

Tags: c++, static-array

I have a class with a static char array.
The size of the array is given to me in `argv`.

I want to do somthing like this:

```
class ABC {

public:
  static char *buffer;
  ABC(int size) {
    ABC::buffer = new char[size];
  }

}

// in other file:

ABC tempVar(atoi(argv[1]));
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I get errors like:

> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char
>   * ABC::buffer" (?buffer@ABC@@2PADA)   gpslib.lib

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't want to do something like that. Buggy.

Comment: What purpose would it serve? I don't see any point. Also, avoid using `atoi`. Use `std::stoi` (introduced by C++11).

Comment: @Nawaz  - what is the difference?

Comment: @kakush: Difference is that `std::stoi` will let you know if the argument is invalid (or there is overlow), while `std::atoi` will be silent.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - I'm using this buffer somewhere else   - that's why it is static. and I have only one instance of this class - so  there should not be any bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `static buffer` exactly once, it has only been declared. Add the following to exactly one `.cpp` file:

```
char* ABC::buffer;
```

Note that everytime an instance of `ABC` is created, the previously allocated `buffer` will be lost (a memory leak) which is not what you want.

A more robust solution would have `buffer` as an instance (non-static) member. An even more robust solution would use `std::string` instead of a `char*` and have dynamic memory allocation managed for you.